# Trying to run ant script but getting Error: Value of annotation member type is of an unexpected type

Tags: ant, javadoc, weblogic-10.x, java-6, build.xml

I'm running ant script (build.xml) which specifies JDK path that is on server:
(WebLogic 10.3.6 which is using jdk 1.6.0.3.)
But facing below error:

```
[wlcompile] [JAM] Error: Value of annotation member type is of an unexpected type: class com.sun.tools.javadoc.ParameterizedTypeImpl   [javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement]
```

Can someone suggest just what may be the problem?